# SSRS : Aligning the output in expected format

Tags: reporting-services

I am having a textbox where the FirstName, LastName, MiddleName are concatenated in user expected format.

FirstName - 'Manoj'
MiddleName - 'Kumar'
LastName - 'R'

**Output :**
LastName, FirstName, MiddleName - *where all the three names as value.* o/p should be as
'R, Manoj, Kumar'

LastName, FirstName - *where i don't have MiddleName value* o/p should be as
'R, Manoj'

**Expression:**
=First(Fields!LastName.Value, "DataSet") +
IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!FirstName.Value, "DataSet"))," ", ", " + First(Fields!FirstName.Value, "DataSet"))+
IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!MiddleName.Value, "DataSet"))," ", ", " + First(Fields!MiddleName.Value, "DataSet"))

it works if i have all the three names. If my MiddleName is empty the output is like below :

'R, Manoj,' the last comma should not come.

Please suggest

Comment: Is middle name actually null/nothing or is it an empty string? Your expression looks OK but only if the middle name is null